# R6034 :Attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, unmanaged, side-by-side, winsxs

I am using botan Libary to generate the Qr Code on vs 2008 I am getting the error "R6034 :Attempt to load  C run time library incorrectly". 
Its MFC/C++ application and
**USE of MFC:** Use MFC in Shared DLL
**Code Generation** : "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)"

I have gone through thread in fourms they are saying manifest files needed to be added bit I already have one, Please help me resolve this issue

Here is my App.exe.manifest.v **"sigcheck.exe - m QrCodeTest.exe"**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
 <security>
   <requestedPrivileges>
     <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false">   </requestedExecutionLevel>
   </requestedPrivileges>
 </security>
</trustInfo>

<dependency>
 <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugMFC" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
 </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
 </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

</assembly>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'D:\Project\QrCodeTest\Debug\QrCodeTest.exe', Symbols loaded.
 QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'
 QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'D:\Project\QrCodeTest\Debug\botan.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'D:\Project\QrCodeTest\Debug\msvcp90.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'D:\Project\QrCodeTest\Debug\msvcr90.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugmfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bfff6c932d60651e\mfc90ud.dll', Symbols loaded.
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\msvcr90d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-con trols_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\msvcp90d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'
'QrCodeTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'
The program '[2708] QrCodeTest.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741502 (0xc0000142).
```

**Dependency**
I ran Debug exe against dependency,here botan should load 
MSVCP90.dll and MSVCR90.dll instead of MSVCP90D.dll and MSVCR90D.dll.Is this the reason foe the mess.If it is how to rectifiey it.

[image]

Comment: Verify that manifest makes it into your app resources. (open compiled binary in VS or resourcehacker). On XP external manifest overrode internal, but this is reversed on vista and onwards.

Comment: @Eugene I checked using resourchecker it is showing manifest file inside the exe

Comment: I have also checked  using sigcheck.exe -m app.exe.It also showing the manifest file.which is same as I posted here.

Answer (score 3):

This must be a problem induced by the way Botan.dll was built.  Clearly you've got the release build of this DLL since it has a dependency on the release version of the CRT.  In general pretty unhealthy mixing that with your debug build that uses the debug version of the CRT, it can cause hard to diagnose runtime errors or memory leaks.

A DLL should have a manifest of its own that states its dependencies. Embedded as an RT_MANIFEST with resource ID 2.  You can check if Botan.dll has one in Visual Studio.  Use File + Open + File, select Botan.dll and you'll see the resources.  Locate the RT_MANIFEST node and open it.  Verify that resource 2 exists and that it states that it requires "Microsoft.VC90.CRT"

With the expectation that you don't see it, triggering the error.  Getting it built with a correct manifest and in general trying to obtain the debug build of this DLL is important to get ahead.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty poped error message.  Clearly you'll need a better build for Botan.dll.  Contact the vendor or owner of the DLL for support.

Comment: Thanks I guess I Solved it..Let me confirm it and than I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded botan source code which is part of Qt Creator Source from
ftp://ftp.qt-project.org/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.1.0-src
and compiled it in Qt Creator.
It will give you botand.dll and botand.lib which is debug version of botan lib.If you download the Windows binary from http://botan.randombit.net/download.html,it won't contain debug version binary which obvious.It might run well for some but will also cause problem for others.So one generate debug binary in this way.

Hope it will help others